# JList doesn't always show the entries

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm trying to make a game lobby, where my server sends me a list of games, and everytime there's a new game, the following code is executed:

```
    public void setGames(ArrayList<Game> games) {
    if (listModel != null) {
        System.out.println(games.size() + " games");
        listModel.clear();
        int index = 0;
        for (Game game : games) {
            listModel.add(index, game);
            index++;
            System.out.println(index);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listModel.getSize());
}
```

However, sometimes the list doesn't show any entry, but the output does say:
6 games
1
2
3
4
5
6
6

Screenshot:
[image: See screenshot]

I did check my file wether or not the listModel got cleared, entries got removed, or anything happened to the listmodel, but that isn't the case...

When I'm adding repaint to the JList, the bug is still there...
Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Make sure updates to the GUI are performed on the EDT. 3) Given your screen-shots can be summed up with 'new entries do not appear', I find them to be useless (and bandwidth wasting) noise.

Comment: You're violating encapsulation. I'd say this is the root cause of your trouble. If you delegated tasks to the appropriate objects, this wouldn't be an issue. I suggest you read up on the inner workings of the `JList` component.

Comment: are you sure the listModel you are debugging/filling is the same instance as that which is set to the JList?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: What is EDT? I'm adding screenshots just to be clear...

Comment: @SanderDeclerck, EDT stands for Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: @kleopatra: I'm sure it's the same, the only time the list model gets set is in my constructor. I just double checked this.

Comment: Is your Google broken?  Top hit for 'edt+java' points to a relevant Wiki entry.  As as aside, squashed up like that, I find the images to be unreadable.

Comment: okay, then back to step one: see @Andrew Thompson 's first comment. Something fishy is going on ... show your code (in form of an sscce :-)

Comment: I don't know a lot about sscce (in fact, I don't know anything about it, but if necessary, I will check it out), I can tell you that the gui updates aren't made in the EDT, it's in the thread that listens to the server. In which way can I make sure it's done in the EDT?

Comment: read the tutorial chapter on concurrency - you need to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater or a custom SwingWorker

Comment: @kleopatra: the SwingUtilities.invokeLater worked, thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to call repaint on the JList after changing the model.

Comment: Just gave it a try, but it didn't seem to work (see added screenshot)

Comment: I use listModel.clear() to remove all the objects before I add the new list, so I don't get any doubles...

Comment: no, there is never a need for calling repaint - iff the notification is setup correctly

Comment: @kleopatra - what is the answer then?

Comment: @Sander does it never work or does it sometimes work? Can you post the code where you set the model?

Comment: don't know - not enough info. But that's unrelated to your answer being wrong, no matter what the correct answer will turn out to be :-)